# Nvidia graphics card not running

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04

It says the graphics card drivers are installed, and I have installed 390, but I hardly beleive it is actually in use.
I am unsure why the resolution got messed up too, happened sometime during my attempt to get the graphics card working.
[image]

As you can see from this image, the 'About' still shows the intel integrated graphics + the resulution is very small, which I assume is part of this issue.
This is ubuntu 18.04 64bit, I also had similar issues on 16.04 previously. GTX 960m

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379138/nvidia-geforce-gt-710-driver-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Normally the package nvidia-prime should be installed alongside the NVIDIA drivers automatically - to do it manually, open a terminal and execute the following command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-prime
```

Now you can find the tab **PRIME Profiles** in the **NVIDIA X Server Settings** application.

[image]

Comment: Neat. However, it's not showing up still. When I installed it it actually said nothing new was installed. I also noticed now for some reason, it says that I am using a custom driver? https://i.imgur.com/BuL2odD.png
I think it did that after I ran this command:
sudo nvidia-xconfig
That command created a file and I set the contents of that file to blank and that fixed my resolution issues.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Q5tpm6p.png Here you can see what I mean it doesn't show up

Comment: Okay I actually got it back to square 1 now. Resolution fine, I have nvidia-driver-390 selected in the additional drivers. Still says I have inten and it looks as though my issue is getting prime to show up right now.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/2XEUANL.png Maybe this will help figure out the issue?

Comment: Figured it out! I did the initial install wrong. Something with the secure boot I overlooked the first time I installed it. I purged nvidia* and reinstalled it and did the secure boot setup correct this time.