# Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, display

I have Nvidia GeFore GT710 Graphics Card and facing issues with the driver installation. Though I am getting an option to nvidia-driver-470 tested version to install. Once installation, Graphic Card is not getting initiated and resolution is some 600X.  System is only working on Nouveau display driver which is not performing at all and very lag in resolution.  Pleas help.

Answer (score 8):

1. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   sudo apt autoremove
   sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
   sudo apt-get remove --purge "nvidia*"
   ```
2. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
3. Reboot with `sudo reboot`
4. Run the following command to automatically select and install the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver and reboot.

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
   ```

After you have installed the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver with the above command it may be updated to a more up-to-date proprietary Nvidia graphics driver package by the normal software update activity.

Comment: ... and check Secure Boot status.

Comment: Thanks Karel for the information. How to check Step 2 about Nvidia PPA. New to Linux so really need help.

Comment: The software sources are located in `/etc/apt`directory, always in the sources.list file and sometimes also in a file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. You can edit sources.list from the terminal with the `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` command. The keyboard shortcuts for Write Out and Exit are in the bottom panel of the editor.

Comment: Hi Karel. How would I know if Nvidia PPA is added seeing the sources.list

Comment: The line in sources.list might contain a string that says `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` or if not you can compare it to the standard source.lists file in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/443075/) and then check on the internet about any line in your sources.list that looks like it might be pointing to an alternative software source that you might remember adding to your software sources.

Comment: Thanks Karel. I did the steps you suggested. However, After rebooting I got the error message that the 'System is working without the Video Graphics'. When I check the 'Additional Drivers' Tab, It shows 'Using Nvidia Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary,tested). Also I got the following error message when I had run the Nvidia Driver installation command 'sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot'
 'WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level'

Comment: Current resolution shows 1024X768. Where am I doing the mistake.

Comment: How to check the Secure Boot Status. I entered the BIOS but couldn't find the option. I am using a Gigabyte Motherboard

Comment: [Gigabyte UEFI Secure Boot status](https://forum.level1techs.com/uploads/default/original/3X/f/7/f7d90bb462ab3c2e677a7acfeb7ea516793076af.png) I replied to your other comments by editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks Karel. I checked with sudo mokutil --sb-state and it shows :SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

Comment: I will try with your new recommendations and update you soon.

Comment: Hi Karel. I tried the steps. But its not working. After rebooting again got the same error 'Your system is currently running without video hardware acceleration'. Additional driver setting shows 'Using Nvidia Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary,tested). '. Please help

Comment: I checked with sudo mokutil --sb-state and it shows :SecureBoot disabled Platform is in Setup Mode

Comment: Try uninstalling the Nvidia packages again and rebooting and then run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 && sudo reboot`