# Failed to run nvidia driver after install

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, additional-drivers

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 on my external drive. I have an Nvidia graphics card of "01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile] (rev a1)."I have tried installing and running the Nvidia driver many times but have not succeeded.

I was able to install the Nvidia driver through the Linux command.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```

But when I tried to run `Nvidia-semi` then, it gave me an error -

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.”
```

I also tried to switch to Nvidia drivers by selecting the additional driver's options in **software and update**, but it gave me the same error.
I tried to install Nvidia driver 515 from the official Nvidia website but at the end of the installation process, it asked me to

```
An X.509 certificate containing the public signing key will be installed to /usr/share/Nvidia/Nvidia-mod sign-crt-E4B26CB6.der.
The SHA1 fingerprint of this certificate is:E4:B2:6C:B6:5C:AB:E7:CB:68:B5:15:6A:F9:F1:24:0B:7C:6E:47:D3.
```

This certificate must be added to a key database trusted by your kernel for the kernel to verify the module signature. I didn't find anywhere how to do this?

Could you please help me to install and run the driver successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379138/nvidia-geforce-gt-710-driver-installation)

Comment: After install Nvidia driver and reboot. Can you run `lsmod | grep nvidia` to check nvidia driver had been installed?

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Nvidia driver via Ubuntu package manager. You can follow this [Nvidia official document](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html#ubuntu-lts)

Or install Nvidia driver via runfile(use 515.48.07 for example):

```bash
sudo apt install curl build-essential
BASE_URL=https://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla
DRIVER_VERSION=515.48.07
curl -fSsl -O $BASE_URL/$DRIVER_VERSION/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-$DRIVER_VERSION.run
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-515.48.07.run
```

After install driver and reboot the computer. You can check which kernel driver using device via `lsmod | grep -E "nouveau|nvidia"`. If it is not use by Nvidia driver. You need disable nouveau follow up this step:

1. Create a file at /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf with the following contents:

```
    blacklist nouveau
    options nouveau modeset=0
```

2. Regenerate the kernel initramfs:
   `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Run `reboot` command and check driver again.

source:[8.3. Disabling Nouveau](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-nouveau)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have tried to install it via official documents, and it went smoothly, but I am still getting the same error.  
I also tried to install the commands you mentioned. However, it still asks me to "This certificate must be added to a key database trusted by your kernel for the kernel to verify the module signature."

Comment: Maybe is secure boot issue ?  I surfing keyword for "certificate nvidia driver secure boot" inspired by @Pilot6 and get this document. Check it if it is the answer. [Signing the NVIDIA Kernel Module](https://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.48/README/installdriver.html)