# dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration i386

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I broke my apt-upgrade while fiddling with the nvidia drivers trying to get the external display working.

When I run `sudo apt upgrade`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then I do - `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb1:i386:
 libxcb1:i386 depends on libxdmcp6; however:
  Package libxdmcp6:i386 is not installed.
.
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-encode-515:i386:
 libnvidia-encode-515:i386 depends on libnvidia-decode-515; however:
  Package libnvidia-decode-515:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxcb1:i386
 libglx-mesa0:i386
 libxcb-xfixes0:i386
 libglx0:i386
 libxcb-glx0:i386
 libxcb-shm0:i386
 libxcb-present0:i386
 libgl1:i386
 libxcb-sync1:i386
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
 libx11-6:i386
 libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
 libx11-xcb1:i386
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libxext6:i386
 libxxf86vm1:i386
 libxfixes3:i386
 libnvidia-decode-515:i386
 libnvidia-gl-515:i386
 libnvidia-encode-515:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read online that `sudo dpkg --configure -a` should help, but it didn't. Gives an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb1:i386:
 libxcb1:i386 depends on libxdmcp6; however:
  Package libxdmcp6:i386 is not installed.
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxcb1:i386
 libglx-mesa0:i386
 libxcb-xfixes0:i386
 libglx0:i386
 libxcb-glx0:i386
 libxcb-shm0:i386
 libxcb-present0:i386
 libgl1:i386
 libxcb-sync1:i386
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
 libx11-6:i386
 libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
 libx11-xcb1:i386
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libxext6:i386
 libxxf86vm1:i386
 libxfixes3:i386
 libnvidia-decode-515:i386
 libnvidia-gl-515:i386
 libnvidia-encode-515:i386
```

I read online and found this but it didn't help either.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I followed the steps in a similar post [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379140/958046) but it did not help.

On running  the first command `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`, I get an error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit-doc' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-dkms-450-server' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-390' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-headless-418' for glob 'nvidia*'
.
.
Package 'nvidia-opencl-icd-384' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.19.0-32-generic : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (<= 515.86.01-1) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (>= 515.86.01) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (<= 515.86.01-1) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-515 (>= 515.86.01) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running the `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libxcb1:i386 linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.19.0-32-generic linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04` gives me an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libxcb1:i386:
 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 depends on libxcb1.
 libxcb-sync1:i386 depends on libxcb1.
 libxcb-shm0:i386 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.12).
 libxcb-present0:i386 depends on libxcb1.
 libxcb-glx0:i386 depends on libxcb1.
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.12).
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 depends on libxcb1.
 libx11-6:i386 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.11.1).
 libglx-mesa0:i386 depends on libxcb1 (>= 1.9.2).

dpkg: error processing package libxcb1:i386 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
(Reading database ... 228713 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-modules-nvidia-515-generic-hwe-22.04 (5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1) ...
Removing linux-modules-nvidia-515-5.19.0-32-generic (5.19.0-32.33~22.04.1) ...
linux-image-nvidia-5.19.0-32-generic: removing .ko files
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxcb1:i386
```

`sudo apt install libxcb1` gives me the following error. Running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` gives the same error as posted above.

```
libxcb1 is already the newest version (1.14-3ubuntu3).
libxcb1 set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxcb1:i386 : Depends: libxdmcp6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt install libxdmcp6:i386 libxdmcp6` gives an error.

```
libxdmcp6 is already the newest version (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu5).
libxdmcp6 set to manually installed.
libxdmcp6:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.1.3-0ubuntu5).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dctrl-tools dkms libatomic1:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386
  libexpat1:i386 libffi8:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libicu70:i386
  libllvm15:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-525 libnvidia-common-525 libnvidia-compute-525:i386 libnvidia-decode-525 libnvidia-decode-525:i386
  libnvidia-egl-wayland1 libnvidia-encode-525 libnvidia-encode-525:i386 libnvidia-extra-525 libnvidia-fbc1-525 libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386
  libnvidia-gl-525 libnvidia-gl-525:i386 libsensors5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxml2:i386 libxnvctrl0 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 nvidia-compute-utils-525 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-525-open
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-525 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-525
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
22 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/11.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxcb1:i386:
 libxcb1:i386 depends on libxdmcp6; however:
  Package libxdmcp6:i386 is not installed.
.
.
.
dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-encode-525:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libxcb1:i386
 libglx-mesa0:i386
 libxcb-xfixes0:i386
 libglx0:i386
 libxcb-glx0:i386
 libxcb-shm0:i386
 libxcb-present0:i386
 libgl1:i386
 libxcb-sync1:i386
 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
 libx11-6:i386
 libnvidia-decode-525:i386
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
 libx11-xcb1:i386
 libnvidia-fbc1-525:i386
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
 libnvidia-gl-525:i386
 libxext6:i386
 libxxf86vm1:i386
 libxfixes3:i386
 libnvidia-encode-525:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Copy/pasted from a deleted comment: `sudo apt autoremove` still gives an error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies: E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).` Unmet dependencies are preventing you from fixing the problem. If you have added any PPAs to your software sources [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/140246/) will tell you how to fix the unmet dependencies error.