# Nvidia GPU driver installation

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, gpu, amdgpu

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad gaming 3 15ach6 with an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 as dedicated GPU and AMD Radeon integrated GPU 22.04 as a dual boot with Ubuntu and Windows 11. If I install the latest Nvidia driver and reboot a black screen appears saying AMD Radeon found and does not open until I access recovery mode and undo the installed driver and install the open kernel. How can I download the Nvidia driver without a problem? The two GPUs must work together in this laptop and it boot normally, but the wifi disappeared even in Settings.

[image: a screenshot of what happened]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379138/nvidia-geforce-gt-710-driver-installation)