# How to update Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 ti driver

Tags: drivers, updates, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I've been trying to udate my GPU but i can seem to find drivers on Nvidia offical site for my graphic card. I have a Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 Ti (know also as Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 Mobile). Can i use driver for Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 or Nvidia Geforce GTX 1650 SUPER insted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers are generally downward version compatible, sometimes with slightly less functionality. Sideways  version compatible should be OK. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379140/) for instructions about how to automatically select and install the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver that is most compatible with your computer's Nvidia proprietary graphics processor.