# Ubuntu 23. Problem with driver Nvidia 535

Tags: drivers, nvidia

So I wanted install nvidia 535 for my Nvidia graphics card on laptop. I've run command in terminal (sudo apt get nvidia535...). It downloaded and during installation it shows only black screen with only blinking cursor in left top angel. What to do? I don't want to use built-in Intel graphics card

Comment: It's about 15-30 minutes now...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia Geforce GT 710 Driver Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379138/nvidia-geforce-gt-710-driver-installation)